# How to remove unclosed tags(e.g. <strong>) in ckeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

How to remove unclosed tags(e.g. ) in ckeditor?
When I put any unclosed tag within a tag, its closed automatically before closing parent tag. e.g. below my code before render

```
<div>
  <strong>Test unclosed tag 
  <p>
    <span>Hey this is test content to check unclosed tag 
      <a href="google.com">Google</a>
    </span>
  </p
  ><span>Processing...</span>
</div>
```

But after saving content, render content looks like below code

```
<div>
 <strong>Test unclosed tag </strong>
   <p><strong><span>Hey this is test content to check unclosed tag 
     <a href="google.com">Google</a></span></strong>
   </p>
  <strong><span>Processing...</span></strong>
</div>
```

So what I want, if any unclosed tag are there, they should be stripped and remain the content of the tag as plain like below code

```
<div>
  Test unclosed tag 
  <p>
    <span>Hey this is test content to check unclosed tag 
      <a href="google.com">Google</a>
    </span>
  </p
  ><span>Processing...</span>
</div>
```

Note: I am using Drupal 7 with full html and filter html format in CK Editor.

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks